# Query parent & grandparent with self reference on the same table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called firm:

```
class Firm(Base):
    __tablename__ = "firm"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('firm.id'))
    level = Column(Integer)
    parent = relationship("Firm", remote_side=[id])
```

id |   name   | parent_id | level

1  |  name 1  | 0         | 1

2  |  name 2  | 0         | 1

3  |  name 3  | 1         | 2

4  |  name 4  | 1         | 2

5  |  name 5  | 3         | 3

6  |  name 5  | 4         | 3

I would like to:

1) get grandparent name, parent name of a given grandchildren id. I used this one, but it did not work. I got DettachedInstance error when fetching result.

```
ret = db_session.query(Firm).filter_by(id=6).options(joinedload('parent')).options(joinedload('parent')).first() # grandparent id = 1
print ret.parent.parent.name # grandparent name is printed out here => OK
db_session.expunge_all()
return render_template('firm.html', firm_tree=ret);

# here is code in html file
<p>{{ firm_tree.parent.name }}</p> <!-- ==>> OK -->
<p>{{ firm_tree.parent.parent.name }}</p> <!-- ==>> DetachedInstance error -->
```

2) Get all records (level = 3) that match a given grandparent id & a given parent id (this parent is a child of the grandparent)

3) Get all records (level = 3) that match a given grandparent id & no need to care about parent id

I have no idea about 2) and 3).
Any help is appreciated!!!